# Actualizacion a Angular 6

Tags: angular

actualice mi aplicación (anteriormente en Angular 2) a Angular 6 y me funciona correctamente, pero al ejecutarla localmente me aparece esto (Mirar en la foto) que antes del 'Compiled siccessfully' que antes no me aparecía. Saben porque aparece?

[image: Lo nuevo es la i <wdm>]

Answer (score 2):

Es la salida del webpack que tenes configurado en tu proyecto angular.
Lo que hace es unir todo tu codigo y compilarlo en  6 paquetes javascripts básicamente

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
```

En cada uno se guardan los estilos de pagina , codigo tuyo, codigo de terceros, polifills etc

Para mas info [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)

Saludos

Comment: Osea que el 'i <wdm>' que aparece no es ningun error?

Comment: No @SebastianGarciaFischer no es ningún error quedate tranquilo ,es solo información de contexto que provee angular cuando compiló tu aplicación.Espero que te haya servido de ayuda